# Carbon parse date format

Tags: php, laravel, date, datetime, php-carbon

I'm trying to parse a date formated like :

```
2017-09-20T10:59:10.0000000 01:00
```

I'm using Carbon, so i tried :

```
Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-dTH:i:s.u vP', $date)
```

Which output :

```
The timezone could not be found in the database\n
Unexpected data found.\n
Data missing
```

I guess the last timezone argument maybe wrong but i couldn't find how to  parse that date format :/

Thanks for help !

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You'll need to add a sign to the timezone, for example:

```
+01:00
```

Then this will work for you:

```
Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d\TH:i:s.0000000 P', $date)
```

If your string can have `-01:00` but instead of `+01:00` you're getting `01:00`, do this first:

```
$timezone = str_after($date, ' ');
if ($timezone[0] !== '-') {
    $date = str_before($date, ' ') . ' +' . $timezone;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for help, it works ;) There is no way to parse the date without modifying the string ? It's returned by third party service API

Comment: @LouisRocher there is a way but it's more verbose. I'd use this one. You can use another variable to save the original string if you need it for some reason.

Comment: There is a problem... It give no errors but the date is wrong : 1970-01-01 :/ I finally use Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d\TH:i:s+', $date) to ignore what's after 2017-09-20T10:59:10. Thanks for help !

Comment: @LouisRocher it's because of `.0000000`. Usually, APIs always return zeros, so you can skip those. I've updated the code if you'll want an alternative.